# Beginning OpenCL tutorials?

Tags: c++, resources, cross-platform, opencl, gpu

I have seen some videos and articles about how powerful OpenCL can be - and I'm hooked. The problem is there is a LOT less resources out there to help you with OpenCL then .. say OpenGL.

I am looking for some pointers to some beginning OpenCL (e.g. a Hello World tutorial) tutorials and some advanced tutorials as well when I get the hang of it.

Also - how 'cross platform' is OpenCL, how many different operating systems (e.g. Windows, Linux, iOS & Android) could I get an OpenCL program running on.

BTW: I would prefer tutorials on using OpenCL with C++ (not Java etc.) :-)

EDIT: If I were to start developing in OpenCL where would I need to go for downloads like headers & .lib files on a Windows system (On linux you just need to type sudo apt-get install opencl-dev & I think Mac OS X already has it installed?).

Comment: Header files are available from [link](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/).  Lots of resources listed there too.

Comment: I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92788/Introductory-Tutorial-to-OpenCL

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> How 'cross platform' is OpenCL, how many different operating systems
>   (e.g. Windows, Linux, iOS & Android) could I get an OpenCL program
>   running on?

OpenCL is open standard but mostly relies on a driver that a vendor develops for a specific hardware and operating system.

To obtain drivers, c++ lib and information follow the links:

[Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/)

[AMD](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/)

[AMD guide (beginner to relatively advanced)](http://developer.amd.com/download/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf)

[Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl)

[Nvidia guide (beginner to relatively advanced)](http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/download/OpenCL/NVIDIA_OpenCL_ProgrammingGuide.pdf) + [CUDA (to learn more techniques for Nvidia GPUs)](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html)

[Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Intel](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk)

[ARM](http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/sdks/mali-opencl-sdk/)

[Samsung](http://aces.snu.ac.kr/Center_for_Manycore_Programming/SNU-SAMSUNG_OpenCL_Framework.html)

[Qualcomm](https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/adreno-sdk.zip)

Comment: Is iOS support Opencl ?

Comment: @Mohan this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847255/is-available-opencl-on-ios) talks about iOS and OpenCL